# Apache doesn't start in XAMPP at all

Tags: apache, xampp

I am trying to start apache server since morning but it doesn't start at all.
I have changed the main port from 80 to 8012 and done everything that I could after reading Q&As on forums on internet, but I am unable to start it. Here is a screen shot of my XAMPP control panel

[image]

just for information i am using apache 2.4, php 7 and mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the installation, you might save it a different folder name by renaming it. Upon trying to start the xampp the system cannot find the file path.